Tricky response against the London system
I am 1900 chess.com rapid player. I am looking for some opening recommendations with black against the London. I find myself struggling to reach positions that suit my style.
I am genuinely tired of seeing it, it hurts my soul.
I play the classical Dutch and the a6 QGD against 1.d4. So depending on your proposition I am cool with d5 and f5 against the London. I love dynamic play and complications, I am not afraid of being worst in the opening (+1;1.2) I mean I play the Dutch. I just find that positions are very boring, I am looking for something to take the wind out of a London player, take them by surprise. I am just tired of always having to take risk and just end up drawing or losing. Like come on, this is not the candidates, it's chess.com rapid games.

Despite the prevalence "How to CRUSH" (punish, destroy, etc) content, there is no instant death ray for the London System, There is no shortage of videos, websites, and other content with Anti-London opening ideas.
The HangingPawns recommendations may be relevant since he is ~1980 FIDE (classical).
Recommendations from IM Levy Rozman (GothamChess):
IM Levy Rozman (GothamChess) has a video entitled Want To Crush The London System?. Some positions involve some risk on Black's kingside. The moves are designed to make London players uncomfortable. The video makes it clear some lines involve Black's f-pawn.
[StartFlipped "1"]
[Title "From IM Levy Rozman"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 (2. Nf3 Nc6 (2... Bf5) (2... Nf6 3. Bf4 Bg4 4. e3 e6 5. Bd3 Bd6 6. O-O Qe7 7. c3) 3. c4 Bg4) 2... c5 3. e3 (3. dxc5 Nc6 4. Nf3 f6) (3. c3 Nc6 4. Nf3 Bg4 5. e3 e6) 3... cxd4 4. exd4 Nc6 5. c3 f6 6. Nf3 g5 7. Bg3 h5 8. h4 g4 9. Nfd2 Bf5 *

Why HangingPawns gave up the London System:
Stjepan Tomic (~1980 FIDE), also known as HangingPawns on YouTube, has a video explaining four setups for Black that equalize in the London and claims these led him to abandon the London as an opening for White.

I'm not playing the London in tournament chess anymore. These 4 setups
are the reason why. They allow black to equalize or even be better by
force! So against a prepared opponent, you're the one who has to fight
for an advantage in the opening. That's not good when you have the
white pieces

The 4 Setups for Black: 4 Setups that made me Quit the London System

Transposition to the Exchange Caro-Kann
Fighting 2.Nf3 with Qb6
The Boring battery draw
The Qb6 draw

How do I play the Dutch against the London?:
GM Simon Williams (GingerGM) plays the Dutch against the London.

Longer Chess Games #32 Climbing the 2500 mountain (slowly...) Dutch vs London System
Longer Chess Games #62 Dutch vs London System

Other Anti-London Ideas:

Master Class | Defeating The London System | Chess Speedrun | Grandmaster Naroditsky; See also Catching the London off Guard With QB6!!
Beat The London System! || Learn The Ultimate
Defense by Agadmator (be aware)
Beat the London System with my
Anti-London by
Pawngrubber
How To CRUSH The London System | ChessKid

